# Qt and MSVS2010 - Project don't create files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm trying create Qt Project in MSVS2010 but VS don't create all files (no Debug and Release files) so I can't build project.

How to fix it?

Comment: Try to include more description in your question, e.g. what steps did you perform to get to where you are now? What is your project structure like? This will help people to help you.

Comment: I agree with the above. We can not help if you do not give us some information about the problem. This is not a common problem. At least I have never ever had this in the 5 years I have developed with Qt on windows.